# Изменение SELECTED VALUE у списка SELECT через JAVASCRIPT

Tags: html, javascript

Есть вот такой список:

```
<select id="estimateA">
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="Н">Н</option>
</select>`
```

Есть вот такой `javascript`:

```
function mark() {
    document.getElementById("estimateA").value = "5";
}
```

Судя по тому, как написали в интернете, то после выполнения функции `mark()` значение списка "estimateA" должно быть установлено `selected value="5"`. Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У тебя в selecte нету значения 0. Смекаешь, что не так?

Comment: Теперь переделал. Написал "5". Но проблема, как была, так и осталась.

Comment: @Никита___  всё работает http://jsfiddle.net/aqs6vz0o/

Comment: Очень странно). В моём файле, в котором я всё это делаю, не работает. Тогда придётся пересматривать исходный код.

Comment: Но всё же - спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Что пишет в консоли браузера?